# Connecting to MySQL from Java to WAMP / MAMP Pro

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, wamp, mamp

I am trying to connect from java to a MySQL database from an external computer on a machine hosting WAMP and other hosting MAMP Pro. The connection to WAMP is fine but on MAMP Pro, I get the following error.

```
              String userName = "user";
              String password = "pass";
              String url1="jdbc:mysql://<IP Address>:3306/dbname";
              Class.forName ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance ();
              conn1=DriverManager.getConnection (url1, userName, password);


The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. 
The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

I had changed the privellages in both the server by going to Privellages in PhpMyAdmin and chaning host to any host under Login Information. Worked for WAMP but didn't work for MAMP Pro.

Any suggestions?

Comment: R there any firewalls ? R u certain packet makes through to the machine ?

Comment: There are no firewalls. How do I check if the packet is making through the machine?

Comment: Did you check the MAMP port? The MAMP default appears to be set to 8889 instead of the mysql default of 3306.

Comment: I changed the default MAMP MySql port to 3306 in MAMP Pro

Comment: Did it solve the problem ? Do you want to mark it as resolved ?

Comment: No it didn't.. I still can't connect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm answering my own question but after some struggle I found the solution. Hopefully it will help people like me in future.

I opened MAMP Pro and on Server - General tab I clicked

```
File => Edit Template => MySql my.conf and changed 
line no 37 from 
bind-address=127.0.0.1 to bind-address = <my server's IP Address>
```

Comment: in my case, MAMP Pro on Mac OS X, I just commented out the line: 
MAMP_skip-networking_MAMP